# DPAPI output buffer memory management

Tags: c++, windows, security, dpapi

I'm using `CryptProtectData()` and `CryptUnprotectData()` APIs for data encryption and decryption in my App.

Reading the [API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dpapi/nf-dpapi-cryptprotectdata), it's not clear why `LocalFree()` needs to be called against the output buffer after usage. The example code on that page does not invoke `LocalFree()`, is that a miss?

What's also missing in the documentation (the main reason for this question) is that, how is `DATA_BLOB::pbData` for the output managed by DPAPI? Can I manage the memory for the output buffer myself? If I can, how do I know the output buffer size of the encrypted data in advance so that I can allocate a large enough buffer for `CryptProtectData()` or `CryptUnprotectData()` to use?

Here is a code snippet on how I'm using `CryptProtectData()`:

```cpp
DATA_BLOB dataIn;
DATA_BLOB dataOut;
dataIn.pbData = (BYTE *)"Hello world";
dataIn.cbData = (DWORD)strlen((char*)pbDataInput);

if(CryptProtectData(&dataIn, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, &dataOut))
{
    printf("Encrypted data size: %d", dataOut.cbData);
    // LocalFree(dataOut.pbData); // Is this needed? Why? How do I manage dataOut.pbData by myself?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Reading the API documentation, it's not clear why `LocalFree()` needs to be called against the output buffer after usage.

Because `CryptProtectData()` dynamically allocates an output buffer and gives it to you, so you need to free it when you are done using it.

> The example code on that page does not invoke `LocalFree()`, is that a miss?

Yes.

> how is `DATA_BLOB::pbData` for the output managed by DPAPI? Can I manage the memory for the output buffer myself?

Not with `CryptProtectData()`, no.  You must use the buffer that it gives you.

If you want to use your own buffer, use [`CryptProtectMemory()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dpapi/nf-dpapi-cryptprotectmemory) instead.

> If I can, how do I know the output buffer size of the encrypted data in advance so that I can allocate a large enough buffer for `CryptProtectData()` or `CryptUnprotectData()` to use?

`CryptProtectData()` handles that for you when it allocates the dynamic output buffer.

`CryptProtectMemory()` encrypts inline, using the same buffer for both input and output.  So you are responsible for ensuring that the buffer is large enough to hold the output.  Its documentation says:

> `[in] cbDataIn`
>
> Number of bytes of memory pointed to by the `pData` parameter to encrypt. The number of bytes must be a multiple of the `CRYPTPROTECTMEMORY_BLOCK_SIZE` constant defined in Wincrypt.h.

So, you would simply take the size of your input data and round it up to the next multiple of the block size.